# Querydsl: how to downcast a join entity?

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm looking for a way to make a join on a one-to-many relation where the many-side is defined through inheritance and the right part of the join is restricted to a specific subclass (downcast).

Say I have the entities below (example taken from [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-downcasting-with-treat-operator.html)):

```java
@Entity
public class Project {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  private String name;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Employee> employees;
    .............
}
```

```java
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE")
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  private String name;
    .............
}
```

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
  private int annualSalary;
    .............
}
```

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {
  private int weeklySalary;
    .............
}
```

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class ContractEmployee extends Employee {
  private int hourlyRate;
    .............
}
```

I can easily build join queries that involve properties defined in the superclass `Employee`, like:

```java
JPAQuery query = ...
QProject project = new QProject("p");
QEmployee employee = new QEmployee("e");
query.join(project.employees, employee);
query.where(employee.name.startsWith("A"));
```

But if I want to access a property of subclass, say `FullTimeEmployee.annualSalary`, and hence restrict the join to that sub-type, how do I do that?

How do I build the the equivalent of following JPQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Project p JOIN TREAT(p.employees AS FullTimeEmployee) e WHERE e.annualSalary > 100000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```java
EntityManager em = ...;
QProject p = QProject.project;
QFullTimeEmployee e = QFullTimeEmployee.fullTimeEmployee;
List<FullTimeEmployee> emps = new JPAQuery<>(em)
    .select(p)
    .distinct()
    .from(p)
    .innerJoin(p.employees, e._super)
    .where(e.annualSalary.gt(100000))
    .fetch();
```

See also this post on the Querydsl forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/querydsl/4G_ea_mQJgY/JKD5lRamAQAJ